# Jquery post Data is not getting to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following jquery

```
 $('#example').tableDnD({
    onDrop: function (table, row) {

        alert(JSON.stringify($('#example').tableDnDSerialize()));
        var data = JSON.stringify($('#example').tableDnDSerialize());

        $.post("/admin/ReorderNews", data, function (theResponse) {
            $("#response").html(theResponse);  
        });
    },
    dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
});
```

Here is the sample data: `example[]=&example[]=1&example[]=2&example[]=`

I m storing the information of table within data, when i post the data to `/admin/ReorderNews/`

which is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReorderNews(string data)
    {


        return Content("ok");
    }
```

it returns OK. however while I m debugging i see that data is `null`.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the data as {"data":data} in post method and use string data in actionresult.

```
    $.post("/admin/ReorderNews", {"data":data}, function (theResponse) {
        $("#response").html(theResponse);  
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is, it s not a type of `String`. how can i make it string?